# Using filteredArrayUsingPredicate always returns an empty array for Core Data fetched objects

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data, nsarray, nspredicate

I'm trying to use NSArray's filteredArrayUsingPredicate: method to filter an array of core data managed-objects. Here's an outline:

```
NSArray *array = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects;

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate
                          predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchString];

NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

This is always returning an empty 'filteredArray'?  I'm guessing it's my predicate, but I know the objects in 'array' are managed objects with a key called "name".  The value of 'searchString' is okay and I have run performFetch: before.

Comment: What do you get when you do a po of the array?  Does the array contain what you think it does?

Comment: Yes, the array was nil - I had thought it was retained from the initial fetch but it wasn't, my mistake. My table view searching is much quicker now it doesn't require a round-trip to the data-store on every search string change. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your predicate is fine.

I would double-check array and searchString:

```
NSArray *array = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects;

NSLog(@"array = %@",array);
NSLog(@"array count = %d",[array count]);
NSLog(@"searchString = %@",searchString);

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate
                          predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchString];

NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Thanks - again a bit of debug, in the code, or using the debugger, is your friend.